# How do I rename a "group by with rollup" column name while maintaining its "NULL" value in super-aggregrate rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, mariadb, rollup

The following SQL statement

```
SELECT MONTH(start_date) month, name, SUM(pins) pins FROM Table
GROUP BY MONTH(start_date), name WITH ROLLUP
```

Should display as

```
1    jim 10
2    jim 15
3    jim 20
NULL jim 45
```

Instead, it produces the following output:

```
1 jim 10
2 jim 15
3 jim 20
3 jim 45
```

As per the MySQL document:

*The NULL indicators in each super-aggregate row are produced when the row is sent to the client. The server looks at the columns named in the GROUP BY clause following the leftmost one that has changed value. For any column in the result set with a name that matches any of those names, its value is set to NULL. (If you specify grouping columns by column position, the server identifies which columns to set to NULL by position.)*

Apparently, the insertion of "NULL" into a super-aggregate column is completed AFTER the aliasing of fields, and because the "month" column alias in the SELECT field list DOESN'T match the EXACT string used in the "GROUP BY" statement, the value for the "month" column in the super aggregate row is thus considered "undefined" and gets assigned the last value displayed, AND NOT the "NULL" it ideally would have.

I've tried all sorts of "tricks" to work around this and have the column alias created AND keep the super-aggregate value "NULL", have not been able to do so.

Any thoughts or ideas welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you delete your previos question and re-asked it again?

Comment: How does it produces that kind of output? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a809fbe400ae803eaa96cf1b3b58bf3b

Comment: The original posting was apparently too light on details, and was closed, with the suggestion that I either edit the comment and add more detail, or delete and repost. As editing didn't seem to "re-open" the question, I elected to delete and repost.

Comment: It produces that kind of output by virtue of the data in table. The issue isn't with the data and thus posting it is not salient. The issue is with column aliasing when GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP is being used.